# Newly created files ignore Linux ACL permissions

Tags: linux, permissions, composer-php

**I have an issue with Linux ACL. Here is my work flow:**

Set ACL permissions on empty directory:

```
sudo setfacl -Rdm g:www-data:rw /var/www/mysite/html/vendor/
```

Change directory:

```
cd /var/www/mysite/html/
```

Install composer packages:

```
composer install
```

Verify installed file permissions:

```
ls -la vendor/
```

All the newly created files and folders belong to my user group instead of belonging to the `www-data` group like it should...

```
drwxrwxrwx+  3 john john    4096
```

**What am I missing here?**

Note: If my user creates a file or a directory, the correct group permission will be applied. The problem only happens with the composer command.

Comment: Nevermind _why_ it's not working. Doing this is a bad idea. `vendor` should not be writeable by your web PHP process at all. What you are trying to do is wrong, so it's lucky you are not having success at it.

Comment: **Why** is this an issue? Is there any reason you need this? Maybe Composer adjusts the permissions on its own?

Comment: @NicoHaase Good question. I *think* I need this because my webserver can't serve the files generated by composer since it doesn't own them nor belong to their group. I always get permission errors after installing a package. I have to manually add all the files to the www-data group to fix it.

Comment: Please share more details about the error message you are facing. Usually, you should never serve any file from the `vendor`  folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found what I was doing wrong. I was confusing file "ownership" and file "permissions".

`setfacl` is used to set default "permissions" for files created in a directory. What I actually needed was to set default "ownership". This is done by setting the "setgid flag" with the `chmod` command *after* properly setting the directory group and user ownership.

I wanted all newly created files in my project directory to belong to the user "john" and the group "www-data".

```
chown -R john:www-data /srv/www/myproject
```

Now we set the "setgid flag" on the directory and all newly created files will belong to `john:www-data`:

```
chmod +s /srv/www/myproject
```

That's all and there's absolutely nothing wrong with setting the www-data group on your served files if you set verything else properly. In fact, the most upvoted anwser related to Laravel file permission on Stackoverflow (800+ upvote) recommends this exact method. Those who disagree never provide a better working solution.

To conclude, Unix permissions is a complicated topic. Few people understand how to properly set permissions on a production server, many fluent programmers are newbies when it comes to Linux. Take answers you read on SO with a grain of salt.